# Function is not being loaded unless resize or click function is used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to execute a function which was defined in the start of the script, lets call this function initialize. This function also uses a variable, lets call it login, which is defined by a php file that includes my jquery script file after defining the variable login.

php/html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

login           = '<?php echo $login; ?>';
...
</script>
<!-- script is included -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

jquery:

```
function initialize(){
    $("." + login).remove();
}

jQuery.moreContent = function moreContent()
{
    //more content is loaded
    ...
    initialize();
}
```

the moreContent function is then loaded, I can see more content appearing on my screen but initialiye is not loaded. only if I use a function like resize (in the end of the script.js file) it works

jquery (in the end of script):

```
//load function initialize
initialize();
//this function doesnt work too, I tested if it even loads and it does (used a number that was increased by one whenever function was loaded which actually happened...)
//however the wished element with the class of variable login is not removed

//resize function
$(window).resize(initialize);
//this one suddenly works 
...
```

I have no idea why it suddenly works with the other function and why it doesnt work in the other cases

Comment: You need to wait until the document is ready before accessing the `$("." + login)` element, more details [HERE](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: I did... I even tried to change the class to the value of login which didn't help either :/

Comment: May be initialize function is getting overwritten in jquery scope try changing name for a while.

Comment: `jQuery.moreContent`? Why are you adding a method on `jQuery` object itself?

Comment: Cause I load it in the php depending on an if clause...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code and make it run once the document is ready, like this:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    // run all your functions here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the variable login is empty in the other function, or you are giving thst a different value.

Try with a global variable to test it, like

```
window.login = script_php
```

And try again, in this ways, the login variable is global, or pass this variable as a parameter in the function.

Comment: Then try adding just the initializer function in a document.ready, not all the function. In load new content, when you call again the function initializer, put in in document ready

Answer (score 0):

> the moreContent function is then loaded, I can see more content appearing on my screen but initialize is not loaded.

That is not exactly what happened. You have attached a function as method directly to `jQuery` object but **did not invoke it**,

```
jQuery.moreContent = function moreContent()
{
    //more content is loaded
    ...
    initialize();
}
```

You won't get any fruitful benefit from doing it this way. You have just added a method to an `object` (jQuery in this case) which is not invoked yet. In any case you do not need to add it as a method to `jQuery` object itself. You can do it easily without this as following.

```
function initialize(){
    $("." + login).remove();
}

// this is a global function right now, use it anywhere you want.
function moreContent()
{
    //more content is loaded
    ...
    initialize();
}

// document ready...
$(function(){
    moreContent();
});
```

You can rearrange the code and remove the unnecessary `function` layers (depends upon your code structure) and use it like this.

```
$(function(){
    // more content...

    initialize();
});
```

> if I use a function like resize (in the end of the script.js file) it works

It worked because it is attached directly to `window` by jQuery on `resize` event.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // The code inside will work whenever user resizes the window.
    // It does not need to be hooked up inside document ready.
});
```

> I have no idea why it suddenly works with the other function and why it doesnt work in the other cases

The reason it worked inside event handlers is because you hooked up your functions to run as a callback function to them. You have set it up correctly in `click` or `resize` event but not in `load` event. In `load` event you just created a function and added the it as a method to `jQuery` object but did not invoke it. The only and only way a [function runs inside JavaScript is when you suffix parenthesis](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/).

```
function demo()
{
    // do something...
    return "Done";
}

// a named function "demo" got created, but not invoked.

demo;  // returns the whole function literal, not invoked yet.

demo(); // invoked, returns Done
```

So continuing from this, adding it as a method to `jQuery` will not load it, until you invoke it e.g.

```
jQuery.myNewMethod = function myNewMethod() {
    return "Hey there :)";
}

// jQuery loaded, but where is my method ?? (@__@)
// let's invoke it then...

jQuery.myNewMethod();  // invoked the function using parenthesis!
// returns "Hey there :)"
// Now i can see you go (^__^)
```

Comment: My fruitful benefit from doing this way is I can load this function in the php which I cannot with your method...

Comment: _"My fruitful benefit from doing this way is I can load this function in the php which I cannot with your method"_ I do not agree, do you mean you can not call a plain JavaScript function other than this?

Comment: I can of course but I want to call it in the php depending on certain algorithms...

Comment: In that case, revise your post with some relevant details.